# My python program dont save in excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My python program only saves the first row but doesn't save the other columns.
On my Track.xlsx file when I press the save button, the program only saves the first line the rest does not save it and it is as if it did not take into consideration the text inside the various textboxes and comboboxes.

I am a beginner, can anyone help me?

```
from cProfile import label
from copyreg import clear_extension_cache
from distutils.command.clean import clean
from importlib.resources import path
from sqlite3 import Row
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas
from openpyxl import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from ast import main
from cgitb import text
#import curses
#from curses.textpad import tb
#import email
from faulthandler import disable
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
from operator import index
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from turtle import pd, width
from unicodedata import name
from webbrowser import get
import openpyxl
import xlrd
from openpyxl import workbook
import pathlib

# Comandi
def load():
    path=filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df=pandas.read_excel(path)
    print(df)
def save():
    mese = entry2.get()
    altezza = entry3.get()
    peso = entry4.get()
    mmagra = entry5.get()
    mgrassa = entry6.get()
    utente = entry7.get()
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A1'] = "Mese"
    ws['B1'] = "Altezza"
    ws['C1'] = "Peso"
    ws['D1'] = "Massa Magra"
    ws['E1'] = "Massa Grassa"
    ws['F1'] = "Utente"
    ws['A2'] = mese
    ws['B2'] = altezza
    ws['C2'] = peso
    ws['D2'] = mmagra
    ws['E2'] = mgrassa
    ws['F2'] = utente
    wb.save(r'C:\Users\lricci\Desktop\SERVER\web\Gym Tracker\Gym Tracker v1.0\track.xlsx')
    showinfo("Salvataggio")
    file1 = pandas.read_excel("track.xlsx")
    file2 = pandas.read_excel("trackn.xlsx")
    all = [file1, file2]
    append = pandas.concat(all)
    append.to_excel("track.xlsx", index=False)
def delete():
    entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry3.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry4.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry5.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry6.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry7.delete(0, tk.END)

# Main frame
windows = tk.Tk()
windows.geometry("400x350")
windows.title("Gym Tracker")
windows.resizable(False, False)

#Frame 2
frame1 = Frame(windows, width=150, height=30, highlightcolor="white",highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1).place(x=120, y=2)
label1= Label(windows, text="GYM TRACKER").place(x=150, y=7)
frame2 = Frame(windows, width=500, height=1, highlightcolor="white",highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1).place(x=2, y=45)

# Combobox Mese
label2 = Label(windows, text="Mese").place(x=110, y=60)
cb1 = Combobox(windows, values=['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno','Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre']).place(x=200, y=60)
entry2 = tk.Entry(windows)

label3 = Label(windows, text="Altezza").place(x=110, y=90)
tb3 = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=90)
entry3 = tk.Entry(windows)

label4 = Label(windows, text="Peso").place(x=110, y=120)
tb4 = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=120)
entry4 = tk.Entry(windows)

label5 = Label(windows, text="Massa Magra").place(x=110, y=150)
tb5 = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=150)
entry5 = tk.Entry(windows)

label6 = Label(windows, text="Massa Grassa").place(x=110, y=180)
tb6 = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=180)
entry6 = tk.Entry(windows)
# Combobox Utente
label7 = Label(windows, text="Utente").place(x=110, y=210)
combobox = Combobox(windows, values=['Erika', 'Lorenzo']).place(x=200, y=210)
entry7 = tk.Entry(windows)

# Bottoni
btdelete = tk.Button(windows, text="Elimina", command=delete ,width=8, height=1).place(x=170, y=310)
btload = tk.Button(windows, text="Load", width=8, height=1,command=load).place(x=300, y=310)
btsave = tk.Button(windows, text="Salva", width=8, height=1, command=save).place(x=50, y=310)
windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide more complete code ? In particular, where is `pd` defined ?

Comment: Hi, I give you the complete code. ```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

Two imports name are conflicting:

```
import pandas as pd
```

and

```
from turtle import pd, width
```

So when you call `pandas` functions by using `pd`, Python tries to call them on the `pd`function of `turtle`.

(You can notice the error is about a function, because `pd` is a function of the turtle package, not a module like `pandas`).

To fix this, you should import the turtle package  `import turtle` and use `turtle.pd()` when you need the `pd` function from `turtle`, and directly `pd` when you need the `pandas` module.

Comment: hello and thanks for the help I am a beginner.
I wanted to ask you when I'm going to import I have to do:
import pandas as pd
And
import turtle as turtle.pd right?

Comment: Hi ! pd is a function from the turtle module, so `import turtle as turtle.pd`  will import the `turtle ` package under the name `turtle.pd` but not the pd function. You can do  `import pandas as pd` and `import turtle` then use `turtle.pd()`in the code. You can also just  `import pandas` and write `pandas`everytime instead of `pd`. Or you can  `import turtle.pd as tpd`  which is sort of a custom alias. In any case, I really advice you to read an explaination about the imports, ideally the official one https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html (seems complicated but read it calmly ahah)

Comment: I thank you infinitely for your availability I have made the change to the code, currently it still does not save on the excel file

Comment: Above I changed the code and uploaded the updated one, could you help me?
I'm a beginner

Comment: Please be more precise, why doesn't it work, what is the error message, ... Can you do a updated section in the first post, where you precise all the new problems ?

Comment: I updated the post section above, hope you can help me out, thank you very much so much

Comment: But what is the problem ?

Comment: on the excel file only the first line is saved while the rest is not